# TLS 1.0 - issues if I disable it?

Tags: tls

I am integrating a .NET web application with Salesforce via the Partner WSDL and SOAP API.

I am currently getting an error

> > UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https.

I know that I can go

```
Setup > Critical Updates > Deactivate the Require TLS 1.1 or higher
```

But what is the downside to this? I mean will they stop allowing us to deactivate it at some point?

How can I make my client application use TLS 1.1 or higher?

Edit:

Here is a part of my app.config. The project is a sample Console application just to test integrating with the SOAP API.

```
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
</startup>
```

I found the solution. In my code I set

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

as per https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000221207

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the feature *for now*, but it will be required within the next five months or so (March 2017 for production orgs). This is because TLS 1.0 is considered "broken" and should not be used to protect data anymore. Your code *will not* able to communicate with any salesforce.com org as of early spring next year.

To upgrade your TLS capabilities, you need to upgrade to .NET 4.5; you can use the [SslProtocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration to select TLS 1.2. The exact method will vary, but the MSDN documentation should give you all the information you need.

Comment: The target .NET framework for the application which calls the API is 4.5.2 but I still get this error

Comment: @andrewb You need to modify your code to use TLS 1.2. Clearly, the code is explicitly asking for TLS 1.0, probably as an artifact from when it was originally developed, assuming it's a few years old. You need to check your code and/or any config files you may have. Without being able to see the source, it'd be hard for us to tell you exactly what to do, but the main point of my answer is you must do it or your application will cease to work. You've got a few months to figure this out, though.

Comment: I added the supported runtime from app.config